# How to validate this form correctly using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a javascript form like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/create_session/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="id-form">
        <tr>
            <th valign="top"></th>
            <td>
                <div class="error_main">
                    <p style="color: #009900; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color:red;">{{ server_error }}</span> {{ connec_ok }}{{ successful }}</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Session Name :</th>
            <td>
                <input id="session_name" {{ disabled }} value="{{ session_name }}" name="session_name" class="inp-form" type="text" onchange="validateSessionName()" />
            </td>
            <td id="session_error"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Source Server Path :</th>
            <td>
                <input id="server_path" {{ disabled }} value="{{ server_path }}" name="server_path" onchange="validatePath()" class="inp-form" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td id="path_error"><span style="color:black"><em>Eg: 10.1.1.43:/home/sachet/test_data</em></span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Source username :</th>
            <td>
                <input id="source_username" {{ disabled }} name="source_username" class="inp-form" type="text" onchange="validateUsername()" />
            </td>
            <td id="username_error"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Source Password :</th>
            <td>
                <input id="source_password" {{ disabled }} name="source_password" class="inp-form" type="password" onchange="validatePassword()" />
            </td>
            <td id="password_error"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top"></th>
            <td>
                <input name="make_default" {{ disabled }} {{ checked }} type="checkbox" id="make_default" />
                <label style="font-size: 13px;" for="make_default">Make the session default</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="submit" name="create_session" value="Submit" id="submit" class="form-submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="form-reset" />
                <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- end id-form -->
</form>
```

I want to do two kinds of validation to the given form. Except Make default checkbox, every input box shouldn't be empty. And I want each field to satisfy this regex:

```
filter = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
```

When the user clicks on Submit button without filling any value, I want to show field required on right hand side of each field. Also, if the user doesn't satisfy the input field while filling the form I want to show invalid data thus I have added `onchange`. I have already done the onchange part now I want to show field required on each field if the user submit empty form. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var session_name    =   $("#session_name").attr("value");
        var server_path     =   $("#server_path").attr("value");
        var source_username =   $("#source_username").attr("value");
        var source_password =   $("#source_password").attr("value");

        if(session_name==''){
            document.getElementById('session_error').innerHTML="Field Required!";
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
        }
        else if(server_path==''){
            document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Field Required!";
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
        }
        else if(source_username==''){
            document.getElementById('username_error').innerHTML="Field Required!";
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
        }
        else if(source_password==''){
            document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML="Field Required!";
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Tables within tables -- I think you're doing your design wrong. An input form may semantically be tabular data, but its container most likely isn't.

Comment: `<div class="error_main"><p style="color: #009900; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;"><span style="color:red;">` -- ew. Keep the outer `div` or move the class to its parent, and move the rest to the `error_main` class CSS or to a more specific class. Inline styles break separation of concerns (data/presentation), introduce redundancy, are impossible to override from CSS and (in most cases) cause bloated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advice:

- Using `on` for binding the submit event
- Using a function for displaying an error (to not repeat code)
- Not use `document.getElementByID` (you are using jQuery)

So my code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("form").on("submit", function(){
    var session_name    =   $("#session_name").val();
    var server_path     =   $("#server_path").val();
    var source_username =   $("#source_username").val();
    var source_password =   $("#source_password").val();

    if(session_name=='')         displayError('#session_error');
    else if(server_path=='')     displayError('#path_error');
    else if(source_username=='') displayError('#username_error');
    else if(source_password=='') displayError('#password_error');
    else                         return true;
  });

  function displayError(element){
    $(element).html("Field Required!");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with `document.getElementById`? It's longer, but it's also faster (I do agree, however. If jQuery is available, it's more consistent to use it)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `$().click` except for consistency. It is implemented as an alias of `$().on`

Comment: `return false` inside `displayError` does nothing if you do just `displayError(...)`. `return displayError(...)` might work. Also, `displayError` does not do everything the asker's code does.

Comment: If you could use `document.getElementById` (which is faster - which you probably know) use it consistently. That's my point

The `$().click` and `$().on` is just style.

The `return false` thing was an unlucky guess.. too bad.

Comment: This will just show Field required on the first input field for a second and form is submitted.